# Module detected by iPython but not Python in same virtual environment

Tags: python

I'm running a script from a Python 3.7 virtual environment (called daa-develop in code below) on MacOS, getting an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sip'`. When then installing sip after, I get 'requirements already satisfied'.

The peculiar behaviour is that when I use IPython in the terminal, it's able to import sip, but not when I use Python in the terminal.

As below:

```
(daa-develop) :daa-develop $ python
Python 3.7.7 (default, Mar 26 2020, 10:32:53) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
import sip

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sip'
exit()

(daa-develop) :daa-develop $ ipython
Python 3.7.7 (default, Mar 26 2020, 10:32:53) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.13.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import sip                                                              

In [2]:
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the output of `which ipython python pip`?

Comment: (daa-develop) :daa-develop $ which ipython python pip
/Users/neuromantic/miniconda3/envs/daa-develop/bin/ipython
/Users/neuromantic/miniconda3/envs/daa-develop/bin/python
/Users/neuromantic/miniconda3/envs/daa-develop/bin/pip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error can arise your `python` and `ipython` are in different environments. It could have been that you installed `sip` in the same environment as `ipython`, and so `ipython` was able to find it. Perhaps `python` was in a different environment and could not find `sip` (see this [github comment](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1524#issuecomment-225010572) for more info).

Even if that is not the issue, miniconda makes it very easy to start fresh with new environments. I would suggest creating a new environment and re-installing `ipython` and `sip`.

```
conda create --name testing python=3.7 ipython sip
conda activate testing
python -c "import sip"
ipython -c "import sip"
```

Comment: I don't think this is the case because of the output below:

(daa-develop) :daa-develop $ which ipython python pip /Users/neuromantic/miniconda3/envs/daa-develop/bin/ipython /Users/neuromantic/miniconda3/envs/daa-develop/bin/python /Users/neuromantic/miniconda3/envs/daa-develop/bin/pip

Comment: I take this back, it works perfectly. You are a god thank you

Comment: I'm no god but thank you. If this answered your question, please accept it by hitting the green arrow